# Opening and testing a sub-window programmatically made in Vaadin, using Vaadin TestBench

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8, test-bench

Good day, fellow stackoverflow users. I have a problem using Vaadin TestBench in order to test a sub-window.

To be more specific, I've programmed a "popup" window that will be invoked by the main application when such application fails for whatever reason. As this sub-window doesn't have an URL, it will simply be invoked programmatically. I'm having problems coming up with a way of testing this single sub-window, as I have searched and read the Vaadin documentation, but all examples I see involve creating a driver for a certain browser, invoking a URL, accessing its elements and then doing the tests.

All I want is something like this:

```
Window popup = new Window() // Create sub-window (popup) programmatically
// instead of navigating to an URL with a web driver

// Here, I select the elements of the popup and do actions on it
// programmatically
...

// End the test and close the popup window
popup.close()
```

Is there a way of accomplishing this feat? I'm using the latest version of Vaadin on Springboot.

Comment: Unless I'm missing your point, even if it were possible to open a window from TB, you'd be trying to test a different window which has nothing to do with the one from the app, which does not make much sense. It's like trying to see if your fire alarm works by starting a fire at your friend's house and hearing his alarm sound. Just make sure any prerequisites that trigger that window are met (turn off your db, remove a required file, etc), and use the driver to connect to where your app is running, then click the appropriate buttons, or whatever would trigger the window to appear.

Comment: @Morfic What I'm trying to do does make sense in the context of testing that the popup opens and that the button it has that sends the zipped logs works correctly. If I am able to do that from TestBench, I can ignore the part of hooking up the popup to the main application, trigger it, and then press the button. This popup is going to be used by another member of my team that knows how it will be activated. Hooking it up to the main UI, when I know nothing about how and where it will be used is a bad idea in my opinion. I need a way of testing this sub-window without attaching it to main code.

Answer (score 0):

Vaadin Testbench and Selenium use the same base. You can reach the popup in the same way you do in Selenium:

```
driver.switchTo().activeElement();
```

or (if it is an alert)

```
driver.switchTo().alert().submit(); //submit = click OK, maybe it differs from your intention
```

If your "popup" is a separate browser window, you can switch by windowHandle.

driver.switchTo().window();

Hope this helps :)